# Dart-Sass Doesnt get added to my System environment

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I tried Installing Dart Sass and adding it to my system environment
However after I added it to the environment and did a restart the cmd doesnt recognize it and I get this message

```
'--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

    operable program or batch file.
```

I checked the path 10 times and switched between it and the src folder it comes with and no luck sadly
this is the only folder I have in my PATH environment

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting your terminal/computer?

Comment: Restarting didnt work however renaming it to Path helped

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the name should be Path rather than PATH